# Parse Push Notifications: User to User

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

Hi I'm making a messaging app that uses the internet to send messages. I need to give a notification from user a to user b.

I use this code:

```
 if (toUser!= nil){
       parseMessage[@"toUser"]=toUser;


        //PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
      //  [push setQuery://whatshouldiputhere?];
    //    [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"New Message from %@!",  [PFUser currentUser].username]];
      //  [push sendPushInBackground];

    }
```

This code is executed when the message is being sent. This just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Could you please help me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the code you posted does absolutely nothing relevant with Push Notifications. Try this tutorial https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: Yes, but you haven't answered my question.

Comment: @armanb21 it's StackOverflow etiquette to accept answers if they are right, and if not right you should comment on why. This does numerous things, 1) lets future question seekers with the same question know that the solution works 2)gives credit to the answer 3) lets the answerer know their time wasn't wasted 4) lets the answer know that your question was answered and 5) limits duplicate questions of the same structure, because in SO if an answer isn't accepted then the same question can be posted without it being flagged as duplicate. You have 8 questions with no accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Sending Push Notifications from User to User are quite similar to using channels, first you have to do a query to find the user then pass that query into the push notification.

So for example:

User A sends User B a message, you have to do a query to find User B in your backend. You can do that many ways, using channels, arrays etc, but for this example I will use an objectId:

```
-(void)sendPushNotificationToUserBWithObjectId:(NSString *)objectId {

    // Build a query that matches user B's objectId (note you would have to save User B's objectId or retrieve it from a different query
    PFQuery *subQuery = [PFUser query];
    [subQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectId];

    // Build the actual push notification from targeted query
    PFQuery *finalQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    // only return Installations that belong to a User that matches the subQuery & 'toUser' is objectId
    [finalQuery whereKey:toUser matchesQuery:innerQuery];

    // Send the notification.
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:finalQuery];
    [push setMessage:@"Message"];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
}
```

You would call it at any time like this:

```
[self sendPushNotificationToUserBWithObjectId:@"xVyWO18"];
```

where @"xVyWO18" is User B's objectId